Google sign in button with one/multiple sessions breaks the button's width
I am using google sign in service (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button) with renderButton API. It seems to me that the button does not listen to the options you send.
enter image description here
I am trying to make the button's width a bit customised. I am doing the following.
window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(googleButtonRef.current, {
                type: 'standard',
                theme: 'outline',
                text: 'continue_with',
                **width: document.querySelector('.login-box--google-button-container')?.offsetWidth**,
            });

This works well with the button without any session active in the browser, but if you have any active session the button starts to create it's own width and height.
Can you help me with this issue ? How can I fix the width of it ?
PS is there any option of turn off the multi and one session button and let be always be button without session ?

Currently, there is no way to turn off the personalized button when there are active session(s). A workaround is to set size to medium.
